# Set request header from response header value using interceptors - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

My springboot application sets a header parameter value I would like to intercept that value and send it to every request in angular

Serverside:
response.getHeaders().add("HeaderName", "HeaderValue")

Front-end: I have two interceptors where the response value is intercepted in response.interceptor.ts class where I have set the same value as the request header.

1. request.interceptor.ts
2. response.interceptor.ts

Any idea how to achieve this?